# What is $\frac{d}{df}(\frac{df}{dx})$?

Tags: calculus

Suppose we have a function $f(x)$. Does $\frac{d}{df}\big(\frac{df}{dx}\big)$ exist, and if it does, what is the intuition behind it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the chain rule, $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}f}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)=\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}f}\frac{\mathrm{d}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)}{\mathrm{d}u}$.
 Set $u=x$, for $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}f}\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}f}\frac{\mathrm{d}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}f}\frac{\mathrm{d}^2f}{\mathrm{d}x^2}$. Then use $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}f}=\frac{1}{\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}}$ to get $\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)}\frac{\mathrm{d}^2f}{\mathrm{d}x^2}$. Or $\frac{1}{f'(x)}f''(x)$, if you prefer.

Comment: Note that this puts the constraint on whether $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}f}\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}$ can exist since $\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}$ can't be $0$.

Answer (score 2):

By the chain rule it's $f''/f'$ with $g':=dg/dx$. Let's change $x$ to $t$ to discuss an important application in physics. Position $x$ has first two derivatives $v,\,a$, so $a=vdv/dx=d(v^2/2)/dx$. This relates Newton's second law to energy conservation.